# applying some other matrix ( bias or unkown matrix) on perspective projection matrix

Tags: opengl, graphics

i was asked from someone why applying the following unkown matrix on perspective projection matrix  today. but i don't figure out what it is. so i put those code snippet here for helping. thank you in advance.

```
{
    QRectF rect = boundingRect().translated(pos());
    float width = float(painter->device()->width());
    float height = float(painter->device()->height());

    float left = 2.0f * float(rect.left()) / width - 1.0f;
    float right = 2.0f * float(rect.right()) / width - 1.0f;
    float top = 1.0f - 2.0f * float(rect.top()) / height;
    float bottom = 1.0f - 2.0f * float(rect.bottom()) / height;
    float moveToRectMatrix[] = {
        0.5f * (right - left), 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.5f * (bottom - top), 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f * (right + left), 0.5f * (bottom + top), 0.0f, 1.0f
    };          //here,what's the matrix meaning for, can i ignore it.

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadMatrixf(moveToRectMatrix);
    gluPerspective(60.0, 1.0, 0.01, 10.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

   .............................................
```

the moveToRectMatrix was loaded into projection matrix stack before applying perspective projection matrix, what's the matrix stand for? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think moveToRectMatrix is the "viewport" matrix that transform the NDC point (in a normalized device coordinate system, after applying perspective projection matrix) to the point in your painter device.I suppose you are painting into some device instead of window screen.